# How do I destroy a JFrame window?

Tags: java, android

After searching in life cycle I have found that my application needs to use the `destroy();` method. However, when I implement this the application doesn't close. I am trying to apply this to the button `exitButton`. If someone could direct me in the right direction then that would be great.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.webcraftbd.radio;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {        

    static String radioTitle = "Android Live Radio";
    static String radioStreamURL = "http://stream.infowars.com:80"; 

    Button playButton;
    Button pauseButton;
    Button stopButton;  
    Button exitbutton;
    TextView statusTextView, bufferValueTextView;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder;

    private RadioUpdateReceiver radioUpdateReceiver;
    private RadioService radioServiceBinder;

    //Notification
     private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=12345;
     private NotificationManager notifyMgr=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(radioTitle);

        playButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
        pauseButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.PauseButton);
        stopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        statusTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.StatusDisplayTextView);

        notifyMgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        showNotification();

        // Bind to the service
        Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, RadioService.class);
        bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(new Intent(this, RadioService.class));
    }


    public void onClickPlayButton(View view) {
        radioServiceBinder.play();
    }

    public void onClickPauseButton(View view) {
        radioServiceBinder.pause();
    }

    public void onClickStopButton(View view) {      
        radioServiceBinder.stop();
    }
    public void onClicexitbutton(View view) {       
        super.finish();
        super.onDestroy();
    radioServiceBinder.onDestroy();
    radioServiceBinder.stop();
    radioServiceBinder.stopService(getParentActivityIntent());

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (radioUpdateReceiver != null) 
            unregisterReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();

        /* Register for receiving broadcast messages */
        if (radioUpdateReceiver == null) radioUpdateReceiver = new RadioUpdateReceiver();   
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_CREATED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_DESTROYED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_PREPARED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_PLAYING));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_PAUSED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_STOPPED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_COMPLETED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_ERROR));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_START));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_END));
    }

    protected void onDestroy(){

        super.onDestroy();
    }
    /* Receive Broadcast Messages from RadioService */
    private class RadioUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_CREATED)) {
                showNotification();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_DESTROYED)) {
                clearNotification();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_STARTED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(false);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus("Buffering...");
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_PREPARED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus("Rady");
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_START)) {
                updateStatus("Buffering...");
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_END)) {
                updateStatus("Playing");
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_PLAYING)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(false);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showNotification();
                updateStatus("Playing");
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_PAUSED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus("Paused");
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_STOPPED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus("Stopped");
                clearNotification();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_COMPLETED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus("Stopped");
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_ERROR)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus("Error");
            }   
        }
    }

    public void updateStatus(String status) {       
        try {
                if(notifyBuilder!=null && notifyMgr!=null) {
                    notifyBuilder.setContentText(status).setWhen(0);
                    notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID,notifyBuilder.build());
                }
                statusTextView.setText(status);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showNotification() {
        notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(radioTitle).setContentText("");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
    }

    public void clearNotification() {
        notifyMgr.cancel(NOTIFY_ME_ID);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    // Handles the connection between the service and activity
    private ServiceConnection radioConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            radioServiceBinder = ((RadioService.RadioBinder)service).getService();
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            radioServiceBinder = null;
        }
    };
}
enter code here
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4a4a4a"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Classic Christmas Radio"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#c0413b"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cover" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StatusDisplayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/PauseButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Unknown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/StatusDisplayTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_pause"
        android:onClick="onClickPauseButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PlayButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/StatusDisplayTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_play"
        android:onClick="onClickPlayButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/StopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/StatusDisplayTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_stop"
        android:onClick="onClickStopButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/StatusDisplayTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

RadioService.java

```
package com.webcraftbd.radio;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class RadioService extends Service implements OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnInfoListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String radioStreamURL = MainActivity.radioStreamURL;

    public static final String MODE_CREATED = "CREATED";
    public static final String MODE_DESTROYED = "DESTROYED";
    public static final String MODE_PREPARED = "PREPARED";
    public static final String MODE_STARTED = "STARTED";
    public static final String MODE_PLAYING = "PLAYING";
    public static final String MODE_PAUSED = "PAUSED";
    public static final String MODE_STOPPED = "STOPPED";
    public static final String MODE_COMPLETED = "COMPLETED";
    public static final String MODE_ERROR = "ERROR";
    public static final String MODE_BUFFERING_START = "BUFFERING_START";
    public static final String MODE_BUFFERING_END = "BUFFERING_END";

    private boolean isPrepared = false;

    private final IBinder binder = new RadioBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        /* Create MediaPlayer when it starts for first time */
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_CREATED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        isPrepared = false;
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_DESTROYED));
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STARTED));

        /* Starts playback at first time or resumes if it is restarted */
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
        else if(isPrepared) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PAUSED));
        }
        else
            prepare();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        /* If radio is prepared then start playback */
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PREPARED));
        isPrepared = true;
        play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { 
        /* When no stream found then complete the playback */
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        isPrepared = false;
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_COMPLETED));
    }

    public void prepare() {     
        /* Prepare Async Task - starts buffering */
        try {           
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioStreamURL);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        if(isPrepared) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            System.out.println("RadioService: play");
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
        }
        else
        {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STARTED));
            prepare();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        System.out.println("RadioService: pause");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PAUSED));
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        isPrepared = false;
        System.out.println("RadioService: stop");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        /* Check when buffering is started or ended */
        if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_START));
        }
        else if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_END));
        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_ERROR));
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                Log.v("ERROR","MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                Log.v("ERROR","MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                Log.v("ERROR","MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    /* Allowing activity to access all methods of RadioService */
    public class RadioBinder extends Binder {
        RadioService getService() {
            return RadioService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after developing some pseudo and some logic, I have noticed that Andorid doesn't have an `exit` method in the way that you're hoping. When first reading the question I didn't realise that it was Android as I was multi-tasking. As you may notice, almost every android application doesn't have an exit button, and there is a reason for this. The reason being that Android is supposedly meant to load and unload applications through the OS, hence why you don't do it. If the user wanted to exit the application, they would do what they do with every other, enter the multi-tasking menu and swipe it off. Please read the following for more information: http://android.nextapp.com/site/fx/doc/exit

Comment: thnx for your help but can you tell me where to write that code ?

Comment: Well which one worked? The top or the bottom? I'll implement it once you let me know.

Comment: Through looking at your code I am unable to pinpoint where about you create `exitButton`. But if you just place the correct code from my answer above in the same method as the button creation object.

Comment: i really don't understand u , i want to make the exit button to exit all the application , because when i try to close it in other way it starts again by it self and i don't know where to post the code u gave me in ?

Comment: If you just place the first action handler I gave you in the answer above in the same object as where you created the buttons (eg: `JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit application");`) then it should close whenever the button is pressed.

Comment: i know that i disturbed u , but i am sorry , can u edit my code in the post with answer because when i try to put it i get error

Comment: Well is that your full code? I can't see where the buttons are created. if you can point out where they are created I'll be happy to do that for you.

Comment: Please try the above.

Comment: i edited the post and put all my codes , i tried u post but i get error on addActionListener and ActionEvent

Comment: Ok, sorry i forgot that is what Android and not Swing. Please view the edit above, that should work.

Comment: it doesn't work , when i push it doesn't do any thing :(

Comment: Just to double check, you do realize that you cannot exit an application in Android in the way I believe you're hoping to.

Comment: i can't understand u can u explain ? , do u have skype or yahoo to chat because i have low reputation here and i can't chat with u here !?

Comment: I do have Skype, but don't tend to hand it out over the Internet. If you view the answer above I have edited it realising that I was completely off-topic. If you view it now it shall explain what is supposed to happen in Android and why you can't implement an `exit` command.

Comment: i understand what u mean , but the problem in my app that if the user try to close the app by a multi tasking or any other way the app starts again by it self !?

Comment: If you're willing to build the application and send the `.apk` to me I will be willing to test it out on my Nexus 5 device and send you the results.

Comment: i built it and that link for apk (http://www.2shared.com/file/tOZiGOBh/Radio.html)

Comment: When closing the application through the multitasking view there were no issues. It closed and didn't re-open, thus all is fine on android 4.4

Comment: loool how please recheck it and wait and if u can get me the logs , please get me it because i don't know how to get the logs , i tried it in many phones and can't stop it

Comment: I cant get the logs as I have no way of doing it on my current phone. Could you record the issue via a screen capture so I can see the issue please

Comment: that pics for the app after closing it and opening it again , can u tell me the wat to get the log on bluestack ? (http://www14.0zz0.com/2014/05/04/21/159735120.png) (http://www12.0zz0.com/2014/05/04/21/205927299.png)

Comment: I can see that you're not on 4.4, what version are you on? Also, I don't understand you're question.

Comment: i want to see the log of the app to see what the fun make it run again after closing it i tested it on 4.2 and lower and make that problem

Comment: How do I grab the log?